# Zip file downloaded from Apache - OK in Ubuntu, invalid in Windows 7

Tags: php, windows, apache, zip

I'm trying to create a zip archive on the fly for downloading from a website. This must be achievable with the minimum of effort from our clients (eg. no installing special decompression utilities). The sequence of events is:

- A bunch of files are gathered/created.
- PHP (v2.2) uses shell_exec() to call linux zip (v2.31) to archive the files to a single file.
- PHP sends headers as follows (via Apache v2.2.22):

  ```
  Content-Type: application/zip
  Content-Length: (whatever)
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="whatever.zip"
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
  ```
- PHP uses readfile to send the file to the browser.

The zip file received can be opened without trouble using the Archive Manager utility that comes with Ubuntu; however when downloaded using Firefox (recent version) to Windows 7 and opened as a normal zipped folder, it reports that the file is invalid.

Comparison of the original zip file with the downloaded versions reveals that *both* downloaded versions have an extra 16-byte header as follows:

```
2f3c 6f62 7964 0a3e 2f3c 7468 6c6d 0a3e
```

but are otherwise identical.

This header is definitely what is causing the zip file to fail on Windows: when the original file was transferred via network share Windows was able to open it without any difficulty.

The header does not appear to be added to other downloaded files (certainly not PDFs anyway).

My first thought was that Apache was gzip-encoding the stream, but the relevant modules aren't even installed (and the received headers don't mention any compression). Similarly, adding an explicit asis handler for the .zip extension had no effect.

Thanks in advance for any advice or help you can give!

Comment: Have you checked if any garbage is sent before file content is sent? For instance, I would try to comment out line with `readfile` and see what is in response body using Fiddler. Possibly you have something before `<?php`

Comment: It's nice of Ubuntu to unpack this file for you, but if it contains 16 extra header bytes, it's probably corrupt. Can you post the code that sends the file?

Comment: FAngel -- Nailed it! Thanks!

I discounted the possibility when I ran my first checks, because a) I would expect PHP to throw its "content already sent" error when I tried to set the headers (still can't figure out why it didn't), and b) the extra bytes didn't make any sense.

Turns out a template include had accidentally received a bogus </body></html> terminator from its two-generations-removed predecessor... for some reason it wasn't causing problems with the PDF files that were also generated with that template, and it was being munged in some way as to make it unrecognisable...